# ASP.net Image to ListView From Data

Tags: c#, asp.net

Morning guys, Using MS Visual Studio 2012, ASP.net/C# 3.5.(not MVC)

I have a list view that is bound in code behind from my model.
It currently displays on screen as columns with 0, 1 or ''.  i would like to replace these at runtime with images (tick or cross) and show no image if the value is ''.

Now i have the following snippet of code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvSearchUser" runat="server">
<div class="hidden">    
                <div id="<%#Eval("userid") %>" class="target">
                    <div class="emptyTitle" style="width:680px;">
                        <div class="videosViewed">Videos Viewed</div><div class="module13">Module13</div><div class="module12" >Module12</div>
                            <div class ="module11" >Module11</div><div class="module10">Module10</div><div class="totalTime">Total Time</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="videosViewed" ><%#Eval("VideosViewed") %> &nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="module13"> <%#Eval("ModuleNum13") %> &nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="module12"> <%#Eval("ModuleNum12") %> &nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="module11"> <%#Eval("ModuleNum11") %> &nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="module10"> <%#Eval("ModuleNum10") %> &nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="totalTime"> <%#Eval("TotalTime") %> &nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

code behind is :

```
private void ShowGrid()
{
    //dgvUserResults.DataSource = null;
    List<ModelSearchUser> dbuser = runSQL.GetUserFinal(GetSearchInput(), GetCountryInput(), GetUserTypeInput(), GetGroupInput(), GetCodeUsageInput(), GetCompletedInput());
    lvSearchUser.DataSource = dbuser;
    this.lvSearchUser.DataBind();
}
```

please note this is not a datagrid its listview that has divs wrapped inside to act like a grid.

So anyone have a solution to this? (unfortunately one that also works with IE7...shudders*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `ModuleNum13` is and `int` in the datasource when binding, how about:

```
<div class="module13">
    <asp:Image id="tick" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("ModuleNum13") is int && ((int)Eval("ModuleNum13")) == 1  %>' ImageUrl="/image/tick.jpg" />
    <asp:Image id="cross" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("ModuleNum13") is int && ((int)Eval("ModuleNum13")) == 0  %>' ImageUrl="/image/cross.jpg" />
     &nbsp;
</div>
```

And similar for the other fields. This is not elegant but should work...

Comment: had some problems with the sql side to my model using int and int?  so i decided to cast them to a string in sql on the return, so its actually a string im working with.  what would be the syntax for this, i suspect a cast of string but what about the "is int"

Comment: well, i put in is string also added != null and ! = "" but i get a cannot cast error, whats the workaround?